# constants in java annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I've got the following annotation:
@javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue("212") Long bits

I want to reuse the "final static" values that are already defined as the argument for the annotation. Like this one:

final static final long PERMISSIONS = PERMISSION_A | PERMISSION_B; //this is 212

But since annotations require a "constant expression", it's not possible to go:

@DefaultValue(String.valueof(PERMISSIONS)) Long bits

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.valueOf(PERMISSIONS)
```

is not recognized as a compiler-time constant expression, but this is:

```
"" + PERMISSIONS
```

So use:

```
@DefaultValue("" + PERMISSIONS)
```

Obviously it's no general case solution.  There just happens to be a compile-time constant way to construct a String from a constant numeric type.  Say instead you had a String constant representing an integer, and wanted to convert it to an `int` to pass to an annotation, then you'd be out of luck.

Comment: man, this has to be the most simple and useful response I've ever got.